# robots.txt and .htaccess syntax highlight

Tags: .htaccess, sublimetext2, robots.txt

Is there a way to colorcode/highlight robots.txt and .htaccess syntax? E.g. with a SublimeText2 plug-in. I found this, but can't figure out how to install it: https://github.com/shellderp/sublime-robot-plugin

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use Package Control to install the syntax packages you want to use. If you're using Sublime Text without Package Control, you're missing out on a lot.

1. [Install Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) (follow the linked instructions)
2. After restarting, type <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then `Install Package`
3. Install **ApacheConf** and the **Robot Framework** you mentioned

Packages can be added and removed very easily, but greatly enhance and personalize what you can do with Sublime Text.

Comment: I think Robot Framework is test automation package and has nothing to do with robots.txt

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa might be, I installed it and quickly checked a robots.txt file, but looking more closely it appears syntax was only superficially supported. Using Yaml syntax is more meaningful.

Comment: .htaccess +1. Robots still not highlighted though

Comment: To get robots.txt syntax highlighted, install Robot Framework as described above, open .txt file and choose `View -> Syntax -> Robot Framework syntax highlighting` (or Open all with current extension as). 

It highlights all .txt files. To highlight specific file by name see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232312/set-syntax-for-a-specific-file-name-in-sublime-text-2-3