# Set syntax for a specific file name in Sublime Text 2/3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a program that uses a file called `user.cfg` to get its user defined configuration settings.  The odd thing is that they chose the syntax for this file to be Tcl (it's not odd that it is Tcl, it's odd they chose the `.cfg` extension *instead* of `.tcl`).  So, when I open this file in Sublime Text, it doesn't know what syntax highlighting scheme to choose.

What I would like to do is set the syntax highlighting for `user.cfg` to Tcl, but **not** all `.cfg` files to Tcl.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100634/changing-default-syntax-based-on-filename) which is *very* similar to mine, except in that case the special file name had no extension so Sublime Text knew to assign Ruby highlighting to only that one file.  Unfortunately, I have an extension so the solution given there will not work for me.

Is there any known way to get Sublime Text base a highlighting scheme on the full filename?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) plugin.

Comment: Worked great!  Although it took forever to figure out that I had set the Tcl name to "TCL/Tcl", not "TCL/TCL" or "Tcl/Tcl".

Comment: Found a nice explanatory [blog post](https://medium.com/@iturgeon/vagrantfile-syntax-highlighting-in-sublime-text-92bb72a74361) on the topic and the suggested plugin

Comment: This plugin can also apply syntaxes if the file path and/or name matches a specific regex, which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is completely true; however, I thought it would be better to have it here all in one place rather than going on another webpage to find the list of procedure to apply it

## Sublime text 3

This is found [here](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/installation/)

1. Ensure Package Control is installed. Instructions are found here.
2. In Sublime Text, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>＋<kbd>Shift</kbd>＋<kbd>P</kbd> (Win, Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>＋<kbd>Shift</kbd>＋<kbd>P</kbd> (macOS) to bring up the quick panel and start typing `Package Control: Install Package`.
3. Select the command and it will show a list of installable plugins.
4. Start typing ApplySyntax; when you see it, select it.

Restart to be sure everything is loaded proper.
Enjoy!